# Good Cassandra table structure

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra

I have two columns i.e. UserId (128 characters) and data (100 characters).
For query,

`Select data from SimpleTable where user_guid = 'xyzabc123457789sda'`,

a simple table structure to store it in cassandra would be:

```
class SimpleTable(Model):
    user_id = columns.Ascii(primary_key=True)
    data = columns.Ascii()
```

If I have 10 million users then I will have 10 million partitions which is normally not a problem. However, there is an alternative version:

```
class SimpleTable(Model):
    bucketid = int(primary_key=True, partition_key=True)
    user_id = columns.Ascii(primary_key=True)
    data = columns.Ascii()
```

Now, If I make an client level abstraction for bucketid i.e. fixing max number of buckets allowed and calculate bucketid based on the hash of first n bits of user_id, I have a limited number of partitions and a huge advantage with this approach is that now I can optimize writing to the table with unlogged batching (less network overhead, faster writes(maybe)) since I can use bucketid to batch write requests for large number of users.
Assume 10 nodes in clusters and max number of buckets to be 1024 with 10 million users i.e. around 10k users per partition. I can basically batch write for 10k users theoritically. (good number for batching is way lower)
The reads are still the same, just calculation of bucketid is required like this:

```
Select data from SimpleTable where bucketid = '999' and 'user_id' = 'xyzabc123457789sda'
```

The second approach looks like pretty good approach to me but am I missing something?
Am I right into thinking that the only tradeoff is between calculation of bucketId and using cassandra batches for write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other thing to consider, is the size limitations on partitions.  Cassandra has hard limits of 2GB per partition (data) and 2 billion cells (columns) per partition.  This is why partition growth over time can be a problem.

The most common way to "time-proof" is to "bucket" by time.  Fortunately, you seem comfortable with that concept.  The only difference is that a "time bucket" is simply using a time component (month, week, etc) as a composite partition key, instead of just `bucketid`.  Something to consider.

Basically, if your `data` column is small and you won't ever exceed 10k rows/partition, your "bucketing" solution should be fine.